# Converting ant_rules_r3 builds to new SDK main_rules

Tags: android, ant

Trying to convert an existing Android build system using Ant with 'ant_rules_r3.xml' integration from the older SDK to the newer SDK 'main_rules.xml' setup.  We have some custom SVN tasks patched into the 'ant_rules_r3.xml' file too, so it might not be as simple as a file swap.

Are there any guides, info, or blogs on how the SDK has been changed and what I need to do to make the conversion?  Have the tasks and/or parameters changed?

Thanks,
DD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find any change notes or other references when I upgraded my SDK. It took a while for me to realise that they'd changed the name of the file to main_rules.xml. I was pretty annoyed to find that my builds failed.

Firstly you will need the latest 1.8.? version of Ant, 1.7 definitely won't work. I found that if you've overridden the compile target,then the line in the target

```
<src refid="android.libraries.src"/>
```

now needs to be

```
<src refid="project.libraries.src" />
```

I think that was the main thing, though there may be others.

Having had my whinge about the change, I must say that the new obfuscation target worked straight out of the box and has turned out to be useful.

Comment: I got this worked out too.  Brute force code compare was what did it.